# Repeat values using SEQUENCE function in row of dates

Tags: arrays, date, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I've written a formula to create an automatic sequence of working days, based upon a date specified as the start of the month (this value would be in C4). I'm trying to create a burn vs. actuals spreadsheet, so I need the date to be repeated for every single date, one for a projected value, and the one for the actual value.

Right now I'm getting a list of dates, but I'd really like to figure out how to automatically generate a repeat of each date in the list of dates.

```
=TRANSPOSE(ArrayFormula(WORKDAY.INTL(L6,sequence((NETWORKDAYS(eomonth(C4,-1)+1,eomonth(C4,0))-1),1,1,1),1)))
```

The desired outcome would look like this:

11/01/2019, 11/01/2019, 11/02/2019, 11/02/2019, 11/03/2019, 11/03/2019.... etc.

Any and all help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Here's a link to an example. I'm trying to repeat the same date in consecutive cells. This formula lists consecutive working days in a particular month. Because I'm looking to compare forecast vs actuals on each of those days, I need to repeat the columns.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/191m9HeEH9tXLq2q3qkHuFkVVpH0jbxGMBAuIhZOBjEs/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try `REPT`:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TO_DATE(SPLIT(REPT(A1&"♥", 5), "♥")))
```

[image: 0]

---

## UPDATE:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TO_DATE(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(REPT(TRANSPOSE(
 WORKDAY.INTL(A4, SEQUENCE((NETWORKDAYS(EOMONTH(B4, -1)+1, 
 EOMONTH(B4, 0))-1), 1, 1, 1), 1))&"♦", 2)), "♦")))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Does this work with more complex formulas like the one I included above? Here's and example of the formula I'm trying to edit here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/191m9HeEH9tXLq2q3qkHuFkVVpH0jbxGMBAuIhZOBjEs/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: yes it does but still no idea what are you after. (yes, I checked your sheet) you want to calculate difference of days between starting day and each networkday?

Comment: No, I literally want to list out the same date twice and do it automatically. Currently, the sheet is creating single instances. I can get the REPT function to create a duplicate, but only in the same cell, not in the adjacent column.

Currently it populates separate columns, like this:
11/1/19 11/4/19 11/5/19 11/6/19 11/7/19 11/8/19

What I want, is:
11/1/19 11/1/19    11/4/19 11/4/19 11/5/19 11/5/19 11/6/19 11/6/19

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!